# iPhone: CALayer Memory Leak question

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimage, calayer, cgimage

Would the code bellow cause my code to leak? More specifically, am I responsible for releasing the `newImage` or the contents of `mainPageLayer` (which is a `CALayer` object)? I get a memory warning every 4th time that method is called, but cant figure out why...

I also can't figure out why `mainPageLayer.contents = [newImage CGImage];` throws a warning that the argument I am passing is of an incompatible pointer time. The image shows up just fine inside the layer.

```
-(void)setPrimaryPage:(UIImage *)newImage {
 pImageSizeWidth = newImage.size.width;
 pImageSizeHeight = newImage.size.height;

 [mainPageLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pImageSizeWidth, pImageSizeHeight)];
 mainPageLayer.contents = [newImage CGImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the contents property is defined as follows:

```
@property(retain) id contents
```

which means that the `CGImageRef` from `newImage` is retained. Whether your code leaks isn't clear from your code: There's not enough context. It will only leak if `newImage` was retained upon calling your `setPrimaryPage:`.